# SVG Path length in Leaflet Routing Machine

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I am using Leaflet Routing Machine to create map route.

My requirement is, if there are multiple locations like A, B, C, D, E. I am getting the length of svg path from A to E. But i need length form A to B, B to C, C to D, D to E. Please help someone.

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff0nx.jpg)

Red color line is svg path. So, when i click on any marker then i need length from basel to that marker. i mean, i need to get length from basel to neuchatel or basel to bern or neuchatel to bern, etc.

```js
var routeControl = L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: waypoints,
  reverseWaypoints: false,
  lineOptions: {
    styles: [{color: 'red', opacity: 1, weight: 3}]
  },
  geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim({
    serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:8084/'
  }),
  createMarker: function(i, wp, nWps) {
    console.log(wp)
    let custom_icon = L.divIcon({
      iconSize: [100, 20],
      popupAnchor: [-30, -18],
      shadowUrl: '',
      html: '<div class="notification '+wp.name+'" data-pathid="'+(i+1)+'" style="color: #000;background-color: transparent;"><img src="img/blue.png"><span class="city-name">' + latlng[i].name + '</span></div>'
    })
    marker = L.marker(
      [wp.latLng.lat, wp.latLng.lng], 
      { 
        icon: custom_icon
      })
      .bindPopup(latlng[i].name)
      .openPopup()
      .addTo(map);
    // marker.on('click', onMarkerClick);
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: When you sai SVG path length, do you mean literally the number of pixels between vertices in the svg, or ar you referring to the physical distance between points represented by that svg?  Also, show us some code so we can see what you're doing please.

Comment: Hi Seth Lutske, thanks for quick reply. I have updated post, please check.

Comment: HI @SethLutske, i was able to make some more progress and i am able to get physical distance between source and destination and i am also able to get waypoint distance. I need help to figure out, how to convert that distance to svg length.

Comment: What do you mean by “svg length”?